# forever-monitor fails when run with pm2 on digitalocean droplet - Target script does not exist

Tags: node.js, pm2, forever-monitor

I have a node app with forever-monitor.

When I run it locally it works correctly.

When I run it manually on a digitalocean droplet with `node app-fm.js` it also run correctly.

However, when It tries to start with pm2 it get error-ed.

Checking the pm2 logs I see:

```
/root/.pm2/logs/app-fm-out.log last 15 lines:
/root/.pm2/logs/app-fm-error.log last 15 lines:
0|app-fm   | Error: Target script does not exist: app.js
0|app-fm   |     at /root/wa-bot/node_modules/forever-monitor/lib/forever-monitor/monitor.js:170:9
0|app-fm   |     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:78:11)
```

app-fm.js is the entry file (the app run with `node app-fm.js`)

app.js is invoked as follow:

```
var forever = require('forever-monitor')

const fm = new(forever.Monitor)('app.js', {
    max: 1,
    silent: false,
})
```

Both the files (`app-fm.js` and `app.js`) are in the root folder of the project.

The project on digitalocean is in `/root/wa-bot` folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it with:

```
const fm = new(forever.Monitor)('app.js', {
    max: 1,
    silent: false,
    sourceDir: (!process.env.DESKTOP_SESSION) ? '/root/wa-bot/' : null
})
```

For some reason on the digitalocean droplet (running ubuntu 20.04) the `sourceDir` is required while on my ubuntu 20.04 laptop is not.